# auto flush PrintWriter

Tags: java, sockets, buffer

I am wiring a client/server program with Java and I enable auto flush but my code has a bug, when I send first message from client to server, no response comes from server but after that everything is ok. These are my codes :

Client

```
public class Client1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Socket socket = new Socket("localhost",5000);
                    BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
                    PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
                    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
                    while (true) {
                        if (socket.getInputStream().available() != 0) {
                            String in = input.readLine();
                            System.out.println(in);
                        }
                        System.out.println("Enter your message to the server: ");
                        String out = scanner.nextLine();
                        output.println(out);
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        }).start();
    }
}
```

Server

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    ServerSocket serverSocket1 = new ServerSocket(5000);
                    Socket socket1 = serverSocket1.accept();
                    System.out.println("Accepted");
                    BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket1.getInputStream()));
                    PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter(socket1.getOutputStream(), true);
                    while (true) {
                        if (socket1.getInputStream().available() != 0) {
                            String text = input.readLine();
                            System.out.println("got it!");
                            output.println("We got your message!");
                        }
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }).start();
    }
}
```

Can somebody help me? Thanks

Comment: What if you get rid of the `...available() != 0` checks?

Comment: The client is probably waiting for you to type something, when the response arrives, so it doesn't read the response